# schedule my api call for every 60 seconds

Tags: html, angular, timer, publish-subscribe, angular2-services

I am writing a simple angular2 web app that hits an api every 60 secs.
I have an api call that i want to schedule call to, everything works well.

How can i call API every 60 secs?
My code

```
app.componenet (calling class)
  constructor(HttpWebServiceService1: HttpWebServiceService1){
    HttpWebServiceService1.getHTTP()
      .subscribe(//do my stuff here);}
```

Above calls my api calling class

```
import { Chart } from './myCode';

@Injectable()
export class HttpWebServiceService1 {
      constructor(private http: Http) {}
      getHTTP() :Observable<Chart[]> {
        //hit the api and get josn string or error
        return this.http.get('http://XX.XX.XX.XX/test/test').map((res:Response) => res.json()).catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));

  }
}
```

Comment: As long as this won't run on mobile I see nothing wrong with it. Pooling has a big impact on phone battery, keeping the radio on drains it like crazy, check http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000545/ch07.html#INEFFICIENCY_OF_PERIODIC_TRANSFERS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way is just to use `setInterval`. ([see the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval))

you can also leverage RxJS:

```
 Observable.interval(60000)
           .switchMap(() => {
              // return your http call here
              return HttpWebServiceService1.getHTTP()
           })
```

The above will return an observable that tries an http request using your service every 60 secs, and then emits the results of that http request.

Comment: Thx snorkpete. Il check ot out. I need to start a ckunter which i look to for some biz logic in the subscribe. Do you see any issue witg this using your switchmap approach?

Comment: Hi SnorkPete, where do you suggest your suggested code is inserted? In my constructor of calling code?

Comment: you can put in the the `ngOnInit` method of the component that needs the data. Note that you shouldn't have any logic in your component constructors - they should just capture any injected dependencies in properties for use in other methods. Move your initialization logic to `ngOnInit`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interval and then every time the interval emits you can use switchMap to get the result of the http call and then subscribe to it. @snorkpete has a correct answer. If you need to get the data immediately and then every 60 seconds after you can use the `concat` operator to get the result immediately and then switch it to the interval like so:

```js
public getData(){
  return this.getHttpRequest().concat(
          Observable.interval(60000)
          .switchMap(() => this.getHttpRequest()));
}

private getHttpRequest(): Observable {
  return this.http.get('http://XX.XX.XX.XX/test/test').map(res => {
              return res.json();
            });
}
```

## [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/l32Y2HScYBlDxhum6BQu?p=preview)